# possible values of port numbers of Tomcat and required changes in server.xml

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

Which are the possible values of port numbers we can give for Tomcat in Eclipse ?
I know that port numbers are ranging from 0-65535, as shown [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers), but is there any **preferred range**? Should it consist of 4 digits?

Also, when changing those port numbers in Eclipse, why don't we need to change the port number in Tomcat's `server.xml` file too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use whatever number you like, just don't pick one too small to make sure it's not already in use by some service, like 21, 80, 22.. etc

For reference, see this list [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers). This list covers a lot of ports used by different services, but I bet you don't have them all running on your machine, so it won't be a problem if you don't plan using that specific service.. If you want to avoid this kind of issues, there's a really big range to pick a number that is not listed.

> Also, when changing those port numbers in Eclipse, why don't we need to change the port number in Tomcat's server.xml file too?

If you want to change the tomcat listening port you will need to change it on the `server.xml`.. you can find a good tutorial on how to do it [here](http://www.mkyong.com/tomcat/how-to-change-tomcat-default-port/).

You always have to change your `server.xml` content in order to change this tomcat port, but you might be doing it using the user interface Eclipse offers, like in [this other tutorial](http://www.codejava.net/servers/tomcat/how-to-change-port-numbers-for-tomcat-in-eclipse), but in the end, it's just the same, Eclipse modifies the `server.xml` for you.

Comment: But in that list most of the port nos. seems to be reserved, can I also use the reserved ports ? and please answer the second question

Comment: But if I go and check the server.xml, the port no. is not changed and also I can make more than 1 servers in Eclipse and have different port nos. for them, then which one will be put in server.xml ? BTW Thanks for editing my Question and showing interest in answering it.

Comment: @A_J I'm afraid I don't understand where do you change it "in Eclipse"... Is it [here](http://www.codejava.net/images/articles/servers/tomcat/portnumbers/configuration%20page%20for%20Tomcat%20in%20Eclipse.png)?

Comment: I hope it is the middle one in that image,(HTTP 1.1) Currently I have 2 servers in Eclipse with values5667 and 8765, but I checked in server.xml, the value is:-> Connector port="8921"

Comment: From the link you gave I found the answer to my 2nd question: Changing the Tomcat’s port numbers in Eclipse does not affect the default Tomcat installation on our computer (outside Eclipse IDE). It is because Eclipse makes a copy of Tomcat configuration in its workspace, by default. If we notice, there is a node called “Servers” in the Project Explorer/Package Explorer view. Expand this node, we will see: Servers node in Eclipse
Under the hood, Eclipse updates the server.xml file when we make change to the port numbers, just like the way we change Tomcat’s port numbers in general